# django clean function in forms.py does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Im reading a book called "Web development with Django" which I like a lot.
One of the things which gets taught there is that you can change a value coming from the form. I have tested raising errors (validation error from django core) which works fine.
But I can't get the "clean_name" function to work on the input. The function is located at the bottom.

I hope someone here knows what im doing wrong :)

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_regnr(value):
    if value[:3].upper() != value[:3]:
        raise ValidationError(f'{value} is not correct')


class BookingForm(forms.Form):

    SERVICES = (
        ('1', 'Årsservice'),
        ('2', 'Storservice'),
        ('3', 'Bromsservice')
    )

    regnr = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=6, validators=[validate_regnr])
    service = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SERVICES)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    tel = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    datetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))
    kommentar = forms.TextInput()

    def clean_name(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['name']
        return value.upper()
```

Comment: The validators on the field run before the cleaning in the form.

Comment: Sure, but this is a clean method, not a validator? the validator is the one on top, but the clean_name method just changes the input from variable name to uppercase? Or am I missing something :)

Comment: yes, the form field will only hand over the value to `clean_name`, if its validators succeed. So by adding the validator to the field itself, `clean_name` is *never* called, because the `validate_regnr` is called first, and stops the rest of the flow (for that field).

Comment: But the validator in on the field "regnr" and the clean method is on the field called "name"? I just # out the validator and ran the form again, but the clean method wasn't called either...

    regnr = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=6)  #, validators=[validate_regnr])
    service = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SERVICES)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    .....

    def clean_name(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['name']
        return value.lower()

Comment: can you share the view where you process the form?

Comment: Yea I meant that, that's what I have in the code, still doesn't work. Neither your class. Which is strange... ill start a new project and quickly just try to figure this out. Many thanks Willem! Dankjewel :)

Comment: ok I found out why, im outputting the input data from the views.py through:         if form.is_valid():

            for x in form:
                print(x)

Which is probably not that smart. Just did a print(value.upper()) instead of the return value.upper() in the clean_FIELD method and now they both work, the clean method and your class. Nice class btw, didn't know that logic yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of things is important. First it will run the cleaning and validators defined on the form fields itself. Then it will run the `clean_…` methods in the form, and finally, it will run the `clean` method.

This thus means that the validator in the field runs *before* it ever gets to the `clean_name` method. Validators defined on the fields thus can not be satisfied with the `clean_…` methods, simply because control is never passed to these.

You can however do the cleaning before validating by subclassing the field:

```
class UppercaseCharField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        val = super().to_python(value)
        if val is not None:
            return val.upper()
```

and then use that one:

```
class BookingForm(forms.Form):
    # …
    regnr = UpperCharField(
        min_length=6, max_length=6, validators=[validate_regnr]
    )
    # no clean_name …
```

Comment: Thank!

But how does it come when I remove everything but the clean method it still doesn't run?

class BookingForm(forms.Form):
    regnr = forms.CharField(max_length=6, min_length=6)

    def clean_name(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['regnr']
        return value.upper()